# why the prepend functionality not work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making a demo .It will not prepand the first div data div second div data (when user scroll to top .it is not prepand the data).

can you please explain why it is not occurring ?

http://jsfiddle.net/G6jJS/4/

```
$("#fullContainer").scroll(function(){
        if($(this).scrollTop() === 0){
            alert("----")

            $("#firstcontainter").html(secondData);
            $("#secondcontainter").prependTo("#firstcontainter");
        }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Because `#secondcontainer` is a child of `#firstcontainer`, when you call...

```
$("#firstcontainter").html(secondData);
```

you are completely removing `#secondcontainer`. Try this instead...

```
var second = $('#secondcontainer').detach();
$("#firstcontainer").html(secondData).prepend(second);
```

You also had an unclosed `<div>` and some other typos. All fixed up here - http://jsfiddle.net/G6jJS/9/

Comment: @user1542984 Yeah, just noticed that myself

Comment: Fixed. Typo in `secondcontainer` (you had `secondcontainter`). I also fixed the unclosed top-level `<div>` and the various other typos - http://jsfiddle.net/G6jJS/9/

Answer (score 0):

There is no `#secondcontainer` after this code

```
$("#firstcontainter").html(secondData);
```

To fix this, just store the content and prepend it later:

```
var second = $('#secondcontainer')[0].outerHTML;
$("#firstcontainer").html(secondData).prepend(second);
```

Comment: +1 This is the right one, because the entire html content of `#firstcontainter` is replace with `secondData`

Comment: @user1542984 - I didn't say anything about `.detach`. Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/G6jJS/7/

Comment: @user1542984 fixing the [typo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22163014/why-the-prepend-functionality-not-work#comment33635340_22163072) will work for [first time.](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/G6jJS/10/)

Comment: Because `html()` only returns the *inner* HTML, after the first time this runs, there will be no `#secondcontainer`